# If state of checkbox was changed can it be permanently saved on page?

Tags: javascript, html

If checkbox was checked/unchacked I want to save its state permanently on page.
I try smth like this:

```
function saveState() {
        document.getElementById($(this).parent().attr('id')).innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" checked onclick="saveState.call(this)">'
    }
```

and

```
<td id="test"> <input type="checkbox" onclick="saveState.call(this)"> </td>
```

But after page refresh this changes is missed.

Comment: This happens because on post back the check box is reset wat you need to do is make this a server control and on post back maintain the state

Answer (score 3):

You have two options to get the data to persist across page loads:

1. Save it server-side
2. Save it client-side

Using local storage is the quickest client-side option:

```
localStorage.setItem("state", saveState()); // save
localStorage.getItem("state") // get
```

Answer (score 2):

To store the state of the checkbox after page reload:

1. use a cookie. See [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) for some examples.
2. use a server-side session mechanism. Specifics depend on the technology you're using.
3. use HTML5 Local Storage. There are heaps of good articles on this, see [this one](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) on example.

For 1 and 3, using JS, store the checked state of the checkbox and then, after reload, read this state (from cookie or local storage respectively) and, using JS, set the state appropriately.

As a side note, consider using 'change' event instead of 'click' event.

Complete example (assuming your input has `id="i1"`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#i1').prop('checked', 'true' === localStorage.getItem('checked'));

  $('#i1').change(function (ev) {
    console.log('save');
    localStorage.setItem('checked', ev.target.checked);
  });
});
```